# Kotlin: How do I request access to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION from simulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mapbox

I'm working with a maps and when running it on the simulator, the map will not work. In my logs, I get an error telling me that I have to grant access to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. How do I do this in KOTLIN? I can only find answers on S/O with Java. The error I get is:

***location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission***

Comment: You can use the same API as you'd use in Java. You can even copy and paste Java code into your Kotlin files and have the plugin convert it for you.

Comment: "I can only find answers on S/O with Java" The two languages should be/are extremely similar. Additionally, Kotlin is completely interoperable with Java. [You can even use IntelliJ to convert it automatically](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html).

Comment: feel free to do some research of your own and try some stuff before you ask us to do it for you. SO is not the only resource you know

Answer (score 22, accepted):

in your manifest write this line for requesting the location permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

since the permission you are trying to request is labeled as Dangerous permission , you have to request it in runtime

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

in onCreate in your activity or fragment write this

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     val permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)

        }
```

the above code is not recommended in production ready app , it's just ok for testing propose , in production ready app you have to consider this scenarios when you request the runtime permissions  :-

- handle the configuration changes in the middle of permission request process .
- handle the case if the user rejected the permission request first time , and second time .
- show the dialog explaining the reason why you need the permission  or the benefit for user if he grand the permission to you

if you need handle all the above cases , you can try this library 
https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher

or you could do it manually.

Comment: have a crash with 'ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)' on android 6.0 with nothing in log